# Filling an arraylist from a datareader

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist, sqldatareader

I have a problem with how to fill an array list from a data reader

```
string queryDTL = " SELECT * FROM tbl1  ";                 

connection.Connect();
cmd = new OracleCommand(queryDTL, connection.getConnection());
dr_DTL = qcmd2.ExecuteReader();

ArrayList RecordsInfo = new ArrayList();
while (dr_DTL.Read())
{
    RecordsInfo = dr_DTL["number"].ToString();
}
```

The problem is the datareader contain alot of info other than the number but I don't know how to put them in their correct position.

I am still a beginner in this sorry if it sounds stupid.

Comment: Any reason why you're using an `ArrayList` instead of a `List<T>`? How do you want to store the data, if there's more that you're interested in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would be better off with a DataTable and an adapter:

```
    SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
    Conn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Employees", Conn);

    DataTable Employees = new DataTable();

    Adapter.Fill(Employees);

    GridView1.DataSource = Employees;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Of course in your case, use the Oracle versions of the objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a `String` in an `ArrayList`. You have to add the string to the list. 
Ex. :

```
ArrayList RecordsInfo = new ArrayList();   
while (dr_DTL.Read())   
{
       RecordsInfo.Add(dr_DTL["number"].ToString());   
}
```

If you want a list of String the best way is using `List<String>`.
Ex. :

```
List<String> RecordsInfo = new List<String>(); 
while (dr_DTL.Read()) 
{    
    RecordsInfo.Add(dr_DTL["number"].ToString()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to do `RecordInfo.Add`, currently you are reassigning the whole arraylist...

Also if you are retrieving too many columns, just query the columns you need, in your case `number`, not simply `SELECT *` ...

Comment: string queryDTL = " SELECT number, name, phone FROM tbl1  ";                 

connection.Connect();
cmd = new OracleCommand(queryDTL, connection.getConnection());
dr_DTL = qcmd2.ExecuteReader();

ArrayList RecordsInfo = new ArrayList();
while (dr_DTL.Read())
{
    RecordsInfo = dr_DTL["number"].ToString();RecordsInfo = dr_DTL["name"].ToString();RecordsInfo = dr_DTL["phone"].ToString();
}   do u mean like this ?? it still not working